# Karate HTML report not having variable value

Tags: spring-boot, testing, karate, web-api-testing

I am trying to write karate test for my spring boot project. I am using following libs

```
implementation 'com.intuit.karate:karate-core:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:1.4.0'
testImplementation 'net.masterthought:cucumber-reporting:5.7.2'
```

Following is the Junit written  **TestRunner.java**

```
public class TestRunner {
    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:features").outputCucumberJson(true).parallel(2);
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}
```

I have a feature file **test.feature**

```
Feature: Reading file


  Scenario: Read File And Print Data

      * def codeValue = read('file:code.json')
      * print codeValue
      * def data = codeValue.data
      * print data
```

**code.json** file contains

```
{data: "testing"}
```

Now, this feature is working fine & passing all the tests but while generating the HTML report it is having the same line **print data** instead of printing the variable value.

Why the variable value is not getting printed?

**Update**

Here is how my report look like:
[image]

Here, that print statement line is not expandable/clickable

Answer (score 0):

It will appear in the Karate report (click on the line to expand it). I don't think it will appear in the Cucumber report as that is not something we control. I think the best option is for you or the community to investigate and contribute code to either Karate or the cucumber-reporting project to get what you want.

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question & added my report image. In my report that print statement is not clickable line and can't expand to see the output

Comment: @AmanKamani then no other option. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue